# How to remove border of TTK Notebook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

## Problem

My problem is that I need to remove the border for the ttk notebook. I am using ttk as a way of using multiple screens and I have removed the tabs from the notebook by doing: `style.layout('TNotebook.Tab', [])` but when I did that there is this ugly white border around the notebook this is what it looks like:

[image]

I am new to ttk so I do not know much about styling in the ttk module
So how can I remove the ugly white border of the notebook

Comment: Try adding `style.layout("TNotebook", [])` and `style.configure("TNotebook", tabmargins=0)`.

Comment: @acw1668 Yes this indeed worked thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation and wanted to remove the border surrounding Tkinter Notebook. Based on the suggestion from the comment [@acw1668](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67381693/how-to-remove-border-of-ttk-notebook#comment119102348_67381693), I was able to remove the border. I post this answer incase it would help someone with similar problem.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")

style=ttk.Style()
style.layout("TNotebook", [])
style.configure("TNotebook", highlightbackground="#848a98",tabmargins=0)# borderwidth = 0, highlightthickness = 0)

MainNotebook = ttk.Notebook(root, style="TNotebook")
MainNotebook.place(x=16, y=16)

Frame1=Frame(MainNotebook, background="#ffffff", width=200, height=150)
Frame1.pack()     
Frame2=Frame(MainNotebook, background="#ffffff", width=200, height=150)
Frame2.pack()

MainNotebook.add(Frame1, text="Tab1")
MainNotebook.add(Frame2, text="Tab2")

root.mainloop()
```